# How to open pdf as a presentation by default using adobe?

Tags: pdf, view, adobe, fullscreen, acrobat

I am trying to open my pdf as a presentation. I have used initial view properties for that. When I click on the full screen mode it shows me the pdf as a presentation. But I want to view the pdf by default in full screen mode. Whenever I click on the desired pdf it should open in full screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

I forget the specific version where this happened but as a security measure, Adobe products now require that a user confirms that they want to allow the PDF to go into full-screen mode.

Alternatively, you can disable "Enhanced Security" in the preferences dialog to bypass this precaution.